# Building opencv-python from source with videoio off results in file not found error

Tags: python, docker, opencv

The error:

```
  /opencv-python/opencv/modules/gapi/include/opencv2/gapi/streaming/cap.hpp:26:10: fatal error: opencv2/videoio.hpp: No such file or directory
   #include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
```

The docker image command that fails:

```
RUN pip wheel . --verbose
```

Here are my cmake args:

```
ENV CMAKE_ARGS="\
    -D BUILD_JAVA=OFF \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_freetype=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF \
    -D VIDEOIO_ENABLE_PLUGINS=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_TESTS=OFF"
```

I realize that the file is not found because I have videoio off, but it should not be looking for the file in the first place. Any advice?

I've tried

```
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF
```

but no success.

Comment: File a bug on OpenCV's github. Based on the comments in that header (`gapi/streaming/cap.hpp`), it shouldn't be used when videoio is not available.

Comment: thanks will do. I also figured out a work-around with also disabling gapi specifically in tandem: `-D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build opencv without videoio but you must also specifically disable gapi,

-D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF